# Flask issue sending reset password request

Tags: python, flask

**Im having this error on the console**

File "c:\Users\onlyj\Desktop\Repo Git\Flask\Flask App\main\routes.py", line 192, in send_reset_email
token = user.get
_reset_token()
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute'get_reset_to ST /reset_password HTTP/1.1" 500 -

```
def send_reset_email(user):
    token = user.get_reset_token()
    msg = Message('Password Reset Request', 
                   sender      = 'onlyjungletom@gmail.com', 
                   recipients  = [user.email])

    msg.body = f'''To reset yor password, visit the following link:
{url_for('reset_token', token = token, _external = True)}

If you did not make this request then simply ignore this email and no changes will be made.
'''
    mail.send()
```

So, when i hit the "Send pass reset "button on the web page  i get this error "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

**And this is the User model on models.py :**

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username    = db.Column(db.String(20),  unique   = True, nullable = False)
    email       = db.Column(db.String(120), unique   = True, nullable = False)
    image_file  = db.Column(db.String(20),  nullable = False, default = 'default.jpg')
    password    = db.Column(db.String(60),  nullable = False)
    posts       = db.relationship('Post',   backref  = 'author', lazy = True)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}'), '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"
```

Comment: Thanks, so the problem is that you are trying to reference an attribute of the 'User' model with `user.get_reset_token()`. Your user model does not have this feature yet, and is therefore returning an error. One way to fix this would be to change your 'User' model to include the `get_reset_token()` part as shown [here](https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/master/Python/Flask_Blog/10-Password-Reset-Email/flaskblog/models.py).

Comment: Now im having this issue, i put all like the page you sended.                             File "C:\Users\onlyj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\signer.py", line 195, in derive_key
    bytes, self.digest_method(self.salt + b"signer" + secret_key).digest()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'bytes'
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2022 21:16:03] "POST /reset_password HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: Hmm, have you done exactly like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vutyTx7IaAI&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH) video by Corey Schafer explains? I've worked through his course and didn't have issues with this part, so maybe you are missing something in one of your other files? Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486062/the-dumps-method-of-itsdangerous-throws-a-typeerror) question might help?

Comment: I figured out that the problem was mail.send() im trying to send the email to my gmail but it doesnt work, when i remove that email.send it works fine, but it doesnt send it obviously

Comment: Yes, I've had a similar problem. Is the error called `smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError`? If so, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926570/flask-securitys-flask-mail-registration-receives-smtplib-smtpauthenticationerro) post helped me and might be of use to you.